# PHP OOP Class vs Functions vs Static Functions efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, static-methods

Sorry if I am not using the best jargon, but I have run into an issue I want to solve early before I write too much code. Which of these options below is "better"? And is there a better way of doing this? Someone mentioned to me abstracting my code but another class seems to be the last thing I need. Also I feel like there's something I can do by potentially making my "get" function seen below into a public static function so that I can use it differently. (its not static right now)

Here is my situation:

- I have 2 (relevant to this question) classes, DB (database) and Page (for getting my content to display on my website)
- the DB class has a query method that prepares and execute my queries
- the DB class also has methods for inserting, getting, deleting things from the database.
- I now feel that I may not even need my page class because right on the webpage I can just use those DB methods to call my content. (I store all images, content, page title, description in mysql). Is this not a legitimate way to do this? Won't I need to create a new object each time? such as:

  ```
  $pg_ID = 2;
  $title = new DB($pgID);
  $title->get('pages', $pgID, $lang); // 3 tables to pull from for each page

  $images = new DB($pgID);
  $images->get('images', $pgID, $lang);

  $structure = new DB($pgID); // I need these tables mostly because my site is in two languages
  $images->get('pages_list', $pgID);
  ```

I do not like this potential solution just because to me its counter intuitive. Why should I have to create new objects just to reuse a function? However, what I do right now is something I feel is going to get me some hate mail.

```
    $page = new Page();
    $page->find('pages', $pgID, $lang);
    $page->lookup($pgID);
    $page->retrieve('images', $pgID, $lang);
```

These are 3 separate functions in my Page class that perform very similar things. Find gets my pages content out of the database and returns it as an object. Lookup does basically the same thing but only needs to pass one variable because its only to do with the html structure of each page regardless of which language is being accessed. retrieve gets all images from a table that get shown in a slider with different language descriptions. But as you can see, all three functions do basically the same thing! They query the database. Thanks for the help with this I am literally just getting into this OOP and its driving me insane. Stack has been very helpful and I think I just didn't know how to search for this to find the answer. Feel free to point me to other questions/answers that I may have missed. It was hard for me to think of the keywords to search for.

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a new instance of the DB class just to make subsequent calls to the database. Your database function would usually return a result (class/array/whatever you are comfortable with) that you can loop over and output/manipulate. After it returns that result, it should be available to run another query or whatever it needs to do. The database class I use (I wrote) returns an array and I just define a single `$DB` at the top of the page. It is a class with a static connection property so I can also when in a function scope just call `$DB = new DB;` and be connected.

Comment: Just a suggestion - have you considered using already made classes for data/database manipulation? Something like Eloquent, Doctrine or Propel? You could probably learn from those libraries if you were to study them, rather than reinventing the wheel on your own.

Comment: That is definitely something I have not considered. I never new it was an option. Will google those names and see what I can come up with. Thank you for the reply @N.B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we may create other classes indeed, but efficiently so. Maybe we can render DB a public *state* function. I like the idea of creating a database object, pass it as parameter to an other object, which could then format data with the link he just received:

```
$pg_ID = 2;
$db = new DB($pg_id);
$page = new Page($db,$pg_ID);
 // make sure you assign the parameters a private properties in `Page()` ctor.
```

then, from inside your function, you can call images, titles and structures at will from `$this`

```
$title = $this->DB->get('pages', $this->pgID, $lang);
$images = $this->DB->get('images', $this->pgID, $lang);
$structure = $this->DB->get('pages_list', $this->pgID);
```

and you can those other method as well

```
$page->find('pages', $this->pgID, $lang);
$page->lookup($this->pgID);
$page->retrieve('images', $this->pgID, $lang);
```

Now we do not need to create a new object each time we want information from the database.

**Now...**

the way I access member functions here `$this->pgID` is better used by defining a getter: `$this->pgID()`. I like my getter to have the same name as the property. This might not be a very good idea though.

```
private function pgID() {
  return $this->pgID;
}
```

**As for abstract classes..**

I did in fact come very lately into thinking abstract classes were quite cool indeed. I've some problem with wording it, having a constant constructor with custom mandatory functions and possible different implementation of classes seems awesome:

```
abstract class Page {
  function __construct($db,$pgID,$lang,$params='') {
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->pgID = $pgID;
    $this->lang = $lang;
    $this->init($params);
  }
  function pgID() {
   return $this->pgID;
  }
  function lang() {
   return $this->lang;
  }
  abstract function init();
  abstract function retrieve();
}

class Structure extends Page {
  function init($params) {
    // some specific to Structure foo here
  }
  function retrieve($what='pages_list') {
    return $this->db->get($what,$this->pgID,$this->lang);
  }
}

class Image extends Page {
  function init($params) {
    // some specific to Image foo here
  }
  function retrieve($what='images') {
    $images = $this->db->get($what,$this->pgID,$this->lang);
    // plus some foo to resize each images
    return $images;
  }
}
```

ok, hope you're still there! Now we have a Structure and Image class with requisites constructor arguments, generic functions and a custom retrieve function. We could use them that way:

```
$db = new DB(2);
$template = new Structure($db,2,'fr');
$template->retrieve();

$slideshow = new Image($db,4,'en');
$slideshow->retrieve();
```

I do hope you do not have to create a new instance of `DB` if you use a different page id :-)

jokes appart this helps me using classes in a better structured way, as I might have many different classes to represent different parts of a site, but when called from an index all of them will have the same function names, like `retrieve()` or `print()`, `list()`...

Comment: Felix thanks so much for the reply. You obviously know a lot more about this than I do but I think I understand the concept and I will attempt to implement it. Currently, in my Page class when I call new Page(), it instantiates my DB class in the constructor. Is this kind of what you were saying in your first code snippet? Your first suggestion seems to be a more oganized and structured way of implementing my current solution. Correct me if I am wrong. I am still trying to get my head around the abstract class

Comment: constructing the DB class in `Page()` class is *almost* the same thing, the difference is in the time used to implement this construction in each and every class needing the DB, whereas passing it as argument assures you to use the same db credentials in all DB-using classes

Comment: Felix, I ended up implementing part of your solution, being forced to skip the rest just due to my slow brain, nothing on your awesome answer. My "get" function now defines `$title`, `$structure`, `$images` and they use the same db "get" function from my db class. Awesome. I've been able to condense about 50 lines of code to like 15 and do not need my other methods like lookup and retrieve. The part I did not implement was the "getter" you mentioned. Mostly why and how it should be implemented into the current structure. Other than that everythings working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to get into the weeds on a SPECIFIC implementation for you situation, rather I am going to offer some generic guidance.

First off, you shouldn't have to create a separate database object (dbo) for title, images, or structure. Chances are the DSN used for each dbo you are initializing are the exact same, so I would create a singleton dbo which can be shared across multiple objects. For reference take a look at [Doctrine's connection manager](http://doctrine1.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/connections.html).

Secondly, I think your objectification could be implemented better. Following most ORMS implementation, you have a **Record** class and a **Table** class. The Record class is a specific instance of a Record in your schema, whereas the Table class executes queries against your store which may result in multiple records. These results are then hydrated into an array (of records).

So what I would suggest is something like this (code has not been tested and some of it has been stubbed for brevity):

```
class PageTable
{
    public static function getById($id)
    {
        // Validate id, if invalid throw exception

        $dbo = Database::getConnection();

        $stmt = $dbo->prepare('SELECT * FROM page WHERE id = :id');

        $stmt->bindParam(array('id' => $id));

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetch();

        $page = new Page;

        // Hydration
        $page->setId($result['id']);
        $page->setImages($result['images']);

        return $page;
    }
}

class Page
{
    protected $id;

    protected $title;

    public function setId($id){}

    public function getId(){}
}
```

Hopefully this separation of Record and methods affecting a single, or multiple records makes sense. You should take a look at a DBAL, like [Doctrine](http://doctrine1.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/introduction.html#what-is-doctrine).

Comment: At the moment I do have a singleton dbo. I instantiate it in my page class at the moment. It is in charge of preparing and executing any queries that have to do with page info. I also use it in my user class for admins to login and such. It seems that what you are suggesting is to split my page class into two. I think I am missing something. My three similar functions seen above all use my DB function "get" while staying in one class. Is that just a best practices thing?

Comment: If you have a singleton dbo, why are you instantiating multiple dbo instances in your given example? the `new dbo` creates a new database object with 0 consideration for a singleton. If you want a singleton, refer to my point about a connection manager, which is essentially a factory for creating dbo objects based on connection params.